# Android - Cannot resolve symbol for getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, list, fragment

Here's the code for my ItemAdapter which I use as an adapter for list in this way.

```
list.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(thisContext,imageUrl));
```

I'm trying to implement an onclick listener for the button that will add an item to a ListFragment. When I compile, it says "cannot resolve symbol getSupportFragmentManager". See bold below. But I'm pretty sure I imported android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity (see below).
I used the same getSupportFragmentManager in my main activity and it works. I don't understand why it isn't here. And if it isn't, how should I obtain the HeadlinesFragment so that I can add to the list in that fragment?

Appreciate any help I can get here.

Pier.

```
package com.suite.android.menu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
**import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;**


public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context itemPageContext;
private String imagesUrl[];
private static final String TAG = "ItemAdapter" ;

public ItemAdapter(Context c, String[] imageUrl)
{
   super();
   itemPageContext = c;
   imagesUrl = imageUrl.clone();  // copy over


}

private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater()
{
    return (LayoutInflater) itemPageContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // all this is for 1 item in the list

    View theView = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        theView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_image, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.foodTitle);
        holder.image = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
        holder.button = (Button) theView.findViewById(R.id.addOrderButton);
        theView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) theView.getTag();

    holder.text.setText("Item " + position);
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            **HeadlinesFragment headFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.headlines_fragment);**
            headFragment.AddItem("One");
            Log.d(TAG, "Added Item!");
        }
    });

    return theView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
    public Button button;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imagesUrl.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I played around with fragments.  but I believe you can only access getSupportedFragmentManager from an FragmentActivity class.

try this

```
public ItemAdapter(Context c,FragmentActivity activity, String[] imageUrl)
{
   super();
   itemPageContext = c;
   this.activity = activity;
   imagesUrl = imageUrl.clone();  // copy over
}
```

then within the class extending FragmentActivity do this:

```
list.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(thisContext,thisActivity, imageUrl));
```

then within the Adapter do this

```
activity.getSupportedFragmentManager...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I tried passing the Fragment into the adapter. That works as well for my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You may have imported the class, but you aren't in a `FragmentActivity`, you are in a `BaseAdapter` so that method doesn't exist on the class you are in.  If you wanted to call that method on your Activity, you would need to pass the Activity in (as a `FragmentActivity` rather than a `Context`) or make this adapter a private inner class so it has access to the enclosing Activity methods.  That method needs to be called on a `FragmentActivity` object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you've found the answer by now, but this may help others.  I was in a situation perhaps similar to yours with no precise answers for how to work around having an `Adapter` class separate from the `FragmentActivity` class, while needing to access the `getSupportFragmentManager`() within the Adapter.

Passing the context didn't work because it doesn't allowing casting of the FragmentActivity (for reasons I still don't understand).

But I gave up and just saved access to the manager itself and call it directly:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
    super(fm);  
    _fm = fm; // declared in the class "private FragmentManager _fm;"
    _context=context;       
}
```